# A nicer way to do multiple replaces?

Tags: javascript

```
var type = event.type.replace('page', 'Page').replace('init', 'Init').replace('before', 'Before').replace('show', 'Show').replace('hide', 'Hide');
```

Can anyone think of a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Could always put them into an array with a foreach, be easier to maintain, but I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for..

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: What's wrong with this? I would put each `replace` call in separate line, but it looks ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a RegExp with [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), passing a function as second argument (=pure JavaScript):

```
var type = event.type.replace(/page|init|before|show|hide/, function(s) {
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine. There is another way to do it:

```
var type = event.type.replace(/page|init|before|show|hide/g, function(m) {
    return m.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + m.substring(1);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uluwij)

Or in the general case (not limited to the set of strings shown):

```
var type = event.type.replace(/(\S)(\S+)/g, function(m, c1, c2) {
    return c1.toUpperCase() + (c2 ? c2 : "");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uluwij/2)